# Upgraded windows 8.1 automatically shutdown when close screen

Tags: windows-8.1

I upgraded my Windows 8 Pro to Windows 8.1 Pro. It is working fine except for when I'm logging in and waiting to enter password, if I close my laptop (not shut down, just fold), it automatically shuts down my system.

Is it bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a bug, I think the settings changed in the power options of you laptop. Click <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and write in the search `power options`. On the left you should see `Choose what closing the lid does`  click on it. Now change the options and your laptop wan't shutdown when it is folded.